# How do I lock a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, locking

What is the best way to create a lock on a file in Perl?

Is it best to flock on the file or to create a lock file to place a lock on and check for a lock on the lock file?

Comment: side note on how to write Perl:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312/how-should-i-capitalize-perl

Comment: not sure if the perl guys on here are lily to do an 'faq' like C++ has, but I'd say this is a fine example of one

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you end up using flock, here's some code to do it:

```
use Fcntl ':flock'; # Import LOCK_* constants

# We will use this file path in error messages and function calls.
# Don't type it out more than once in your code.  Use a variable.
my $file = '/path/to/some/file';

# Open the file for appending.  Note the file path is quoted
# in the error message.  This helps debug situations where you
# have a stray space at the start or end of the path.
open(my $fh, '>>', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' - $!";

# Get exclusive lock (will block until it does)
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Could not lock '$file' - $!";

# Do something with the file here...

# Do NOT use flock() to unlock the file if you wrote to the
# file in the "do something" section above.  This could create
# a race condition.  The close() call below will unlock the
# file for you, but only after writing any buffered data.

# In a world of buffered i/o, some or all of your data may not 
# be written until close() completes.  Always, always, ALWAYS 
# check the return value of close() if you wrote to the file!
close($fh) or die "Could not write '$file' - $!";
```

Some useful links:

- [PerlMonks file locking tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7058) (somewhat old)
- [`flock()` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html)

In response to your added question, I'd say either place the lock on the file or create a file that you call 'lock' whenever the file is locked and delete it when it is no longer locked (and then make sure your programs obey those semantics).

Comment: Is there a reason why you use append `>>` rather than create/overwrite `>`?

Comment: Note: According to [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) `"To avoid the possibility of miscoordination, Perl now flushes $fh before locking or unlocking it."` Would this flushing eliminate the possibility of a race condition?

Answer (score 11):

The other answers cover Perl flock locking pretty well, but on many Unix/Linux systems there are actually two independent locking systems: BSD flock() and POSIX fcntl()-based locks.

Unless you provide special options to configure when building Perl, its flock will use flock() if available.  This is generally fine and probably what you want if you just need locking within your application (running on a single system).  However, sometimes you need to interact with another application that uses fcntl() locks (like Sendmail, on many systems) or perhaps you need to do file locking across NFS-mounted filesystems.

In those cases, you might want to look at [File::FcntlLock](http://search.cpan.org/~jtt/File-FcntlLock-0.12/lib/File/FcntlLock.pm) or [File::lockf](http://search.cpan.org/~phenson/File-Lockf-0.20/lockf.pm).  It is also possible to do fcntl()-based locking in pure Perl (with some hairy and non-portable bits of pack()).

Quick overview of flock/fcntl/lockf differences:

lockf is almost always implemented on top of fcntl, has file-level locking only.  If implemented using fcntl, limitations below also apply to lockf.

fcntl provides range-level locking (within a file) and network locking over NFS, but locks are not inherited by child processes after a fork().  On many systems, you must have the filehandle open read-only to request a shared lock, and read-write to request an exclusive lock.

flock has file-level locking only, locking is only within a single machine (you can lock an NFS-mounted file, but only local processes will see the lock).  Locks are inherited by children (assuming that the file descriptor is not closed).

Sometimes (SYSV systems) flock is emulated using lockf, or fcntl; on some BSD systems lockf is emulated using flock.  Generally these sorts of emulation work poorly and you are well advised to avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for the fine explanation of the some of the distinctions between the underlying system calls. Wikipedia’s [list of Unix file-locking problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#Problems) should probably be required reading.

Answer (score 7):

CPAN to the rescue: [IO::LockedFile](http://search.cpan.org/~rani/IO-LockedFile-0.23/LockedFile.pm).

Comment: Ahhh!!! Object oriented Perl eek. The IO::LockedFile is implemented using the flock functions

Comment: The CPAN module looks good to me. I'd rather reuse code than spell it out myself every time, even if it's only a couple of lines. Perl OO syntax is fairly hideous, but it works okay.

Answer (score 6):

Ryan P wrote:

> In this case the file is actually unlocked for a short period of time while the file is reopened.

So don’t do that. Instead, `open` the file for read/write:

```
open my $fh, '+<', 'test.dat'
    or die "Couldn’t open test.dat: $!\n";
```

When you are ready to write the counter, just `seek` back to the start of the file. Note that if you do that, you should `truncate` just before `close`, so that the file isn’t left with trailing garbage if its new contents are shorter than its previous ones. (Usually, the current position in the file is at its end, so you can just write `truncate $fh, tell $fh`.)

Also, note that I used three-argument `open` and a lexical file handle, and I also checked the success of the operation. Please avoid global file handles (global variables are bad, mmkay?) and magic two-argument `open` (which has been a source of many a(n exploitable) bug in Perl code), and always test whether your `open`s succeed.

Comment: Does seeking back to the beginning actually overwrite the contents of the file? That was my specific issue. I am testing with the die I was just trying to keep the code simple in the example. I nevere thought of the exploit of the 2 arg open thanks I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite the contents. But I forgot to mention that you need to truncate the file before closing it, to ensure that if the new contents are shorter, the file doesn’t end up with trailing garbage.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be much better to show this with lexical variables as file handlers
and error handling.
It is also better to use the constants from the Fcntl module than hard code the magic number 2 which might not be the right number on all operating systems.

```
    use Fcntl ':flock'; # import LOCK_* constants

    # open the file for appending
    open (my $fh, '>>', 'test.dat') or die $!;

    # try to lock the file exclusively, will wait till you get the lock
    flock($fh, LOCK_EX);

    # do something with the file here (print to it in our case)

    # actually you should not unlock the file
    # close the file will unlock it
    close($fh) or warn "Could not close file $!";
```

Check out the full [documentation of flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) and the [File locking tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7058) on PerlMonks even though that also uses the old style of file handle usage.

Actually I usually skip the error handling on close() as there is not
much I can do if it fails anyway.

Regarding what to lock, if you are working in a single file then lock that file. If you need to lock several files at once then - in order to avoid dead locks - it is better to pick one file that you are locking. Does not really matter if that is one of the several files you really need to lock or a separate file you create just for the locking purpose.

Comment: You should check `close` anyway. You can't do much, but you can at least tell the user and bail out, instead of silently continuing to run as if nothing had happened.

Comment: you should more importantly check if flock failed. Sure, most of the times it will not, but when it does, you'd be in big trouble. Depending on perl flock implementation see [flock(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock), [lockf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf) or [fcntl(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl)

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the [LockFile::Simple  module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LockFile::Simple)? It does most of the work for you already.

In my past experience, I have found it very easy to use and sturdy.

Comment: This looks a bit more complicated than the flock structure. I don't know about flocks concurrency issues but this specifically notes the race condition possibilities of NFS which we will be using.

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;

use Fcntl ':flock'; # Import LOCK_* constants

# We will use this file path in error messages and function calls.
# Don't type it out more than once in your code.  Use a variable.
my $file = '/path/to/some/file';

# Open the file for appending.  Note the file path is in quoted
# in the error message.  This helps debug situations where you
# have a stray space at the start or end of the path.
open(my $fh, '>>', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' - $!";

# Get exclusive lock (will block until it does)
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);


# Do something with the file here...


# Do NOT use flock() to unlock the file if you wrote to the
# file in the "do something" section above.  This could create
# a race condition.  The close() call below will unlock it
# for you, but only after writing any buffered data.

# In a world of buffered i/o, some or all of your data will not 
# be written until close() completes.  Always, always, ALWAYS 
# check the return value on close()!
close($fh) or die "Could not write '$file' - $!";
```

Answer (score 1):

My goal in this question was to lock a file being used as a data store for several scripts. In the end I used similar code to the following (from Chris):

```
open (FILE, '>>', test.dat') ; # open the file 
flock FILE, 2; # try to lock the file 
# do something with the file here 
close(FILE); # close the file
```

In his example I removed the flock FILE, 8 as the close(FILE) performs this action as well. The real problem was when the script starts it has to hold the current counter, and when it ends it has to update the counter. This is where Perl has a problem, to read the file you:

```
 open (FILE, '<', test.dat');
 flock FILE, 2;
```

Now I want to write out the results and since i want to overwrite the file I need to reopen and truncate which results in the following:

```
 open (FILE, '>', test.dat'); #single arrow truncates double appends
 flock FILE, 2;
```

In this case the file is actually unlocked for a short period of time while the file is reopened. This demonstrates the case for the external lock file. If you are going to be changing contexts of the file, use a lock file. The modified code:

```
open (LOCK_FILE, '<', test.dat.lock') or die "Could not obtain lock";
flock LOCK_FILE, 2;
open (FILE, '<', test.dat') or die "Could not open file";
# read file
# ...
open (FILE, '>', test.dat') or die "Could not reopen file";
#write file
close (FILE);
close (LOCK_FILE);
```

Comment: Another solution: open the file in read/write mode from the beginning, with an exclusive lock (LOCK_EX), instead of using a separate lock file.  This will allow you to read and then write the file without closing or releasing the lock.

Answer (score 1):

Developed off of [http://metacpan.org/pod/File::FcntlLock](http://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFcntlLock)

```
use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock :seek :Fcompat);
use File::FcntlLock;
sub acquire_lock {
  my $fn = shift;
  my $justPrint = shift || 0;
  confess "Too many args" if defined shift;
  confess "Not enough args" if !defined $justPrint;

  my $rv = TRUE;
  my $fh;
  sysopen($fh, $fn, O_RDWR | O_CREAT) or LOGDIE "failed to open: $fn: $!";
  $fh->autoflush(1);
  ALWAYS "acquiring lock: $fn";
  my $fs = new File::FcntlLock;
  $fs->l_type( F_WRLCK );
  $fs->l_whence( SEEK_SET );
  $fs->l_start( 0 );
  $fs->lock( $fh, F_SETLKW ) or LOGDIE  "failed to get write lock: $fn:" . $fs->error;
  my $num = <$fh> || 0;
  return ($fh, $num);
}

sub release_lock {
  my $fn = shift;
  my $fh = shift;
  my $num = shift;
  my $justPrint = shift || 0;

  seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET) or LOGDIE "seek failed: $fn: $!";
  print $fh "$num\n" or LOGDIE "write failed: $fn: $!";
  truncate($fh, tell($fh)) or LOGDIE "truncate failed: $fn: $!";
  my $fs = new File::FcntlLock;
  $fs->l_type(F_UNLCK);
  ALWAYS "releasing lock: $fn";
  $fs->lock( $fh, F_SETLK ) or LOGDIE "unlock failed: $fn: " . $fs->error;
  close($fh) or LOGDIE "close failed: $fn: $!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to the lock *file* approach is to use a lock *socket*. See [Lock::Socket](http://metacpan.org/pod/Lock::Socket) on CPAN for such an implementation. Usage is as simple as the following:

```
use Lock::Socket qw/lock_socket/;
my $lock = lock_socket(5197); # raises exception if lock already taken
```

There are a couple of advantages to using a socket:

- guaranteed (through the operating system) that no two applications will hold the same lock: there is no race condition.
- guaranteed (again through the operating system) to clean up neatly when your process exits, so there are no stale locks to deal with.
- relies on functionality that is well supported by anything that Perl runs on: no issues with flock(2) support on Win32 for example.

The obvious disadvantage is of course that the lock namespace is global. It is possible for a kind of denial-of-service if another process decides to lock the port you need.

[disclosure: I am the author of the afor-mentioned module]

Comment: it should be "use Lock::Socket", not "use Lock::Simple"

Comment: Thanks Matija Nalis! I've fixed the example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) Luke.

**Edit:** [This](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7058) is a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

flock creates Unix-style file locks, and is available on most OS's Perl runs on.  However flock's locks are advisory only.

edit: emphasized that flock is portable

Comment: While this is helpful back information it does not really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to reading and writing in one lock...

```
open (TST,"+< readwrite_test.txt") or die "Cannot open file\n$!";
flock(TST, LOCK_EX);
# Read the file:
@LINES=<TST>;
# Wipe the file:
seek(TST, 0, 0); truncate(TST, 0);
# Do something with the contents here:
push @LINES,"grappig, he!\n";
$LINES[3]="Gekke henkie!\n";
# Write the file:
foreach $l (@LINES)
{
   print TST $l;
}
close(TST) or die "Cannot close file\n$!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Flock is probably the best but requires you to write all the supporting code around it - timeouts, stale locks, non-existant files etc.
I trued LockFile::Simple but found it started setting the default umask to readonly and not cleaning this up. Resulting in random permissions problems on a multi process/multi-threaded application on modperl
I've settled on wrapping up NFSLock with some empty file handling.