# Lock a Text File in Perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I lock a file in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920/how-do-i-lock-a-file-in-perl)

Does anyone know how to lock a text file in Perl so only one thing can write to it until it is unlocked? I need something other than setting the read/write attributes. Thanks.

Comment: What operating system and filesystem are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that this is only an *advisory* lock - there is nothing actually stopping another program from going ahead and writing to the file anyway.

Comment: The links[1], they are everywhere[2] : )! Edit: Didn't work as expected. Oh well.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920/how-do-i-lock-a-file-in-perl
[2]: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-lock-a-file?