# Write lock on a yaml file?

Tags: perl, yaml

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920/how-do-i-lock-a-file-in-perl) post explains how to put file write lock on regular files.

But is it possible to put a lock on a yaml file, so only one script at a time can write to it?

I am using `YAML::Syck`, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock a file using [`flock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html). You'll need to open the file first as `flock` operates on filehandles.
Alternatively you can use [`LockFile::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LockFile%3a%3aSimple) from CPAN.

Comment: How can I lock a yaml file with flock? Doesn't it require a file handle?

Comment: @Sandra: YAML::Syck's LoadFile() takes a file name or a file handle. You'd open the file before calling the function, flock it, then pass the handle to LoadFile. It does not, however, prevent any other process from reading or writing the file unless those other processes also use flock.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html). Also, see [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html) under "How can I lock a file".

It's important to note that it's advisory locking anyway, so there is no need to actually lock the .yaml file. You can just lock a lock file (maybe yourfile.yaml.lock) and unlock it when done.

This also gives you the capability to say "this block of operations requires exclusive access", rather than just limit your exclusivity to a single file.