# How do I make a file permanently read-only on Linux so even root can not edit it?

Tags: linux

If I would like to lock a file as read-only. Even root can not use an editor to modify it, just allowing any program to open it read-only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your use case for this?

Comment: Nope. Root can do anything. That's what it means to be root.

Comment: Root cannot write to `/proc/kcore`

Comment: Try `chmod -R a-x /` as `root`.  Now even root won't be able to do anything!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is an ["immutable" bit](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/11/make-your-files-immutable-which-even.html) for files.

Programs (even running as root) won't be able to tamper with the file. Of course, root can un-do the bit, but most programs (especially non-malicious ones) won't get past it.

Set it with

```
sudo chattr +i file
```

Comment: You can undo this by doing `chattr -i file`. How would you make this "immutable" bit immutable itself? I had read in a book that you could remove the `cap_linux_immutable` capability to root, so that root couldn't change the immutable bit any longer without rebooting the computer. The file was thus not totally immutable but you had to reboot with a different capability setting if you wanted to use `chattr` to reverse the immutable bit. I wish I found a way to do this today but I can't find a way now, it seems the utility that permitted this (`lcap`) is no longer part of the main linux distros.

Answer (score 4):

you should have root perms

`sudo chattr +i file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl or another language to create a file lock

[How do I lock a file in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920/how-do-i-lock-a-file-in-perl)

But, root could kill the process can gain access to the file.

Comment: `flock` and `lockf` etc. are just "informative" locks; files which ignore them are not affected by them.