# Flock in Perl doesnt work

Tags: perl, file-handling, flock

I have a Perl file. The user opens a file, reads data and displays the data in grid. user edits it and saves it back to the file.

I am trying to use flock so that when the user reads the file, the file gets locked. I tried below code but it didnt work.

Referring to the accepted answer of this post. [How do I lock a file in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920/how-do-i-lock-a-file-in-perl)

```
use Fcntl ':flock';                         #added this at the start
$filename= dsfs.com/folder1/test.txt;        #location of my file

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;     #file open
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Could not lock '$file' - $!"; #inserted flock before reading starts so that no other user can use this file
#reading of file starts here
#once read, user saves file. 

close($fh) or die "Could not write '$file' - $!"; #release lock after user writes.
```

I guess this is a normal operation without any race around conditions but this doesnot work for me.I am not sure if the perl script is able to detect flock or not.

For testing purposes, i try to open the file before my writing and saving function gets completed. when i try to open the same file before saving gets completed, it means that the lock is not released yet. in this situation if i open the file at backend and edit the file, i am still able to save changes. In practical case, it should not be able to edit anything once the file is locked.

can anyone please suggest me any troubleshooting for this or is my procedure of using flock incorrect ??

Comment: Don't use a bare-string file name; enclose it in quotes.  Do use `use warnings;` and `use strict;` which would have told you to do that.

Comment: Is that really the code you're running? You should be getting a syntax error.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot- i commented out use strict. thats y it didnt give me any errors for the above code i posted.

Comment: Commenting out `strict` is amazing, almost like logging your errors to /dev/null.

Comment: Even without strict, the missing semicolon in `$filename= dsfs.com/folder1/test.txt` will give a syntax error. Please don't comment out `use strict;` when you get an error, and please only copy-and-paste the exact code you're running when you ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot- i edited the post. semicolon is there in my code. i did a typo here. i will make sure to use strict and see the errors i get from it

Comment: @Сухой27- :( i will use strict now and update the post with the errors i get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another problem if your `flock` implementation is based on `lockf(3)` or `fcntl(2)`, which it probably is. Namely, `LOCK_EX` should be used with "write intent", on a file opened for output.

For `lockf(3)`, [`perldoc -f flock`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#flock-FILEHANDLE-OPERATION) says

> Note that the emulation built with lockf(3) doesn't provide shared locks, and it requires that FILEHANDLE be open with write intent.

and for `fcntl(2)`:

> Note that the fcntl(2) emulation of flock(3) requires that FILEHANDLE be open with read intent to use LOCK_SH and requires that it be open with write intent to use LOCK_EX.

A workaround for input files or for more complicated synchronized operations is for all processes to sync on a trivial lock file, like:

```
open my $lock, '>>', "$filename.lock";
flock $lock, LOCK_EX;

# can't get here until our process has the lock ...
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;     #file open
... read file, manipulate ...
close $fh;
open my $fh2, '>', $filename;
... rewrite file ...
close $fh2;

# done with this operation, can release the lock and let another
# process access the file
close $lock;
```

Comment: Or opening in rw mode `+>>` and a lot of seeking.

Answer (score 3):

There's two problems:

- `flock` will block until it can lock. You therefore need `flock ( $file, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB ) or die $!;`
- `flock` (on Unix) is advisory. It won't stop them accessing it unless they also check for a lock.

Comment: @sobrique - it didnt work yet. if i use the above answer, how is it suppose to respond ? will it not let the user open the file itself or will it notify user that the file is in use when he tried to open it ? or it wont let the user make changes. i tried but i am still able to make changes and save it. Please note: i am using a .txt extension. I suppose there should be a different procedure to lock a .txt file and a .csv file

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot- Exactly my concern now. my filename contains the fqdn in it. will tat make a difference ?